# get user language date format in current culture

Tags: c#, .net

By date format I don't mean the one used by `.net` to format date types

Date format shown to the user with a french culture could be `jj/mm/aaaa` (jour = day, mois = month, an = year).
For example in `html`  an `<input type="date" />` would show the format above as an input placeholder.

does .net have this format info available ?

Comment: [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0) ?

Comment: Do you need to get culture info from the HTML page to your dotnet backend in asp.net MVC application or something?

Comment: @xakpc no, the html input type date was only an example of the kind of date format that I need

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the culture (replace **en-US** with your culture:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Or with the Current Culture

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

**RESULTS**
The first will return M/d/yyyy
The second will return (in my case, as I am in Switzerland) dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: no, I need the format to show to the user not to format date, in german it would be perhaps something like TT.MM.JJJJ (tag, monath, jahr)

Comment: True, for Germany/German it will give dd.MM.yyyy (with dots), not TT
No, it seems not to be available

Let me think of an easy solution